# how to implement overload method in TypeScript Interface?

Tags: implementation, typescript

i am new to typescript, here is a interface which i'd like to implement;

```
interface IThing{
    name:string;
    age:number;
    sayHello:{
        (name:string):string;
        (age:number):number;
    }
}
```

**sayHello** has two signatures which indicates overload version. i just don't know how to implement that in a class, any help? thanks.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid TypeScript to me.  Have you had a look at the code samples here? http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial/

Comment: there is no errors occurs via IntelSense, i get this code snippet from the typescript introduction video here: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-TypeScript

Comment: This is perfectly valid TypeScript and this is a valid, straightforward question. Vote to reopen.

Comment: What you have defined in your interface is a `sayHello` object with two different constructors. This is why it is valid TypeScript - it just isn't the TypeScript you are looking for. See the answer from @RyanCavanaugh for overload syntax.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To implement an overloaded function, write all the overload call signatures you want to be visible first, followed by an implementation signature that is a superset of all the overload signatures. Example:

```
class Thing implements IThing {
    // Implement the name and age fields
    name: string;
    age: number;

    // Overload signature #1
    sayHello(name: string): string;
    // Overload signature #2
    sayHello(age: number): number;
    // Implementation signature, not visible to external callers
    sayHello(arg: any): any {
        if(typeof arg === 'string') {
            return this.name;
        } else if(typeof arg === 'number') {
            return this.age;
        } else {
            throw new Error('sayHello can only take string or a number');
        }
    }
}

var x = new Thing();
var n = x.sayHello('world'); // n: string
var a = x.sayHello(42); // a: number
var e = x.sayHello(false); // error: false is not string or number
```

Comment: +1. I would add that you leave out the implementation signature when adding an overloaded method to an interface, you only need that for classes, as shown in this answer.

Comment: this works fine. thanks, is this the only way to do this implementation? i find this overrided mechanism seems to be just used to restrict the type of input-args/return-values? if not i could declare the function signature as sayHello(arg:any):any in my interface, and then stuff the code snippet sayHello(arg:any):any{ //if...else...} in my implementation class. any help clear my confusion?

Comment: @Steve Fenton, sorry i don't understand what you say well, only need that for classes?

Comment: @paulcheung Yes - the implementation signature (the one accepting an argument of type `any` above) is only needed on a class. The other two (accepting arguments of types `string` and `number` above) are the only ones you need to add on an interface.

Comment: @SteveFenton very kind of you!